# How to see who access my ip address from web service via wifi

Tags: xampp, localhost, local

i have little question..

i installed xampp in my local and create php file like this 
C:/xampp/htdocs/test1/index.php

and my friends access my localhost with my ip like in another device like this..
192.18......../test1/index.php

all connected with the same wifi

my questions is, how to see who's accessing my localhost? and can i block who access?

i am using windows 10 :)

Comment: That's a lot of broad questions. One would have to literally write a small book to answer them all.

Comment: win + r -> cmd --help

Comment: See you xampp log . it' contain all informations about requests to your project like adress ip , browser  ...

Comment: thx @MOHAMMED YASSINE Chabli i found it in access.log

can i block that ip or block my folder project for their can't access

Comment: yes , you can by writing a php code on your index project i your case for example

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli i wanna block everyone who access, its possible? just mylocal can access it should not write spesific 1 by 1 ip

i wanna block in 1 folder sir  can u give me reference link.. for learn :)

Comment: you want only people in the same network to access ?

Comment: no sir,  i install xampp but i am in same connection wifi with my friend right now...
i just dont wanna my friend access my project thats why i wanna block all who access my local  because in the same connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find informations about visitor request , please check you xampp apache log file .

here is the code you can add in your index.php to deny access for some adress ip :

```
<?php
    $deny = array("111.111.111", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
    if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
       header("location: http://www.google.com/");
       exit();
    } ?>
```

add the adress ip in $deny array for machine that you won't them to access your project .

in that example , every user that is denied to access , will be redirecting to google .

think to create another page as the forbidden page (forbidden.php) to render your visitors if there are denied to this page .

another way to deny visitors is using .htaccess .

1-go to /htdocs/test/
2-create a file nammed .htaccess (with dot in the beginning)
3- add this code to the file (.htaccess)

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1/24
```

the adress 192.168.1.1/24 must match your network adress . you can check it in your terminal by typing **ipconfig** .
hope that help you

Comment: thx very much sir,

can i block everything who access in 1 folder sir? use include or exnted in every file?

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: i've folder test in htdocs there is file index.php, get.php,set.php etc

i don't wanna everyone (not set spesific ip) access directory test in same connection

Comment: do you mean with the same connexion == the same network ?

Comment: yes sir, in the same network but they cannot access my project

Comment: in that case , you have to configure it with .htaccess . i'm gonna upadate my answer

Comment: sory sir, still not my expectation
but thx for helping, i still can access my project in another device 

10.100.0.207/test. 

my expectation is another device cannot access my web service (my localhost or my project). i wanna only my pc can access my web service not other, even in the same network

Comment: that mean you don't created it on the best way

Comment: sorry sir, its working.. :). but i must access 
127.0.0.1 instead. before iam using localhost in url. thx very much :) sir

Comment: great . enjoy :)